# How to disable "Exchange ActiveSync" while creating a new mailbox using C#

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

How should I disable "Exchange ActiveSync" using C# code while creating a new mailbox in Microsoft Exchange 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute powershell command to disable exchange active sync from c# code.

C# code looks like this:

```
var command = "Get-Mailbox \"name\" | Set-CASMailbox -ActiveSyncEnabled $false";

var runspaceConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
runspaceConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapInException);

using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfig))
{
    runspace.Open();

    using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(command);

        var results = pipeline.Invoke();
        // You can handle results here
    }

    runspace.Close();
}
```